# How to escape Python name error in for loop calling Shell script?

Tags: python, linux, shell

```
 def startdataprocessing (self, widget):
    text_file = open("SRAIdFromPythonInput.txt", "w")
for item in text_file:
    execute('bash ./oneclickdataprocessor.sh')
text_file.close()
```

I have error text_file is not defined. How to fix that? Is it correct to call .sh script over every item in .txt file or I should use Linux shell embedded for loops?

Comment: You should fix your indentation.

Comment: You haven't called your startdataprocessing function.

Comment: You're calling `text_file` which is a variable defined *within* `startdataprocessing`

Comment: Your `for item` loop is **useless**, as you don't pass `item` to your `execute(...`.

Comment: What is the `execute()` function? It's not a standard Python built-in.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your script

```
text_file = open("SRAIdFromPythonInput.txt", "w")
for item in text_file:
    execute('bash ./oneclickdataprocessor.sh')
text_file.close()
```

For calling external shell files consider the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. More in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)